# <Method> is not a member of <Class>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is pretty basic stuff I have done before, but I don't understand why I'm having an issue now. I'm creating an object 'foo' for easy interfacing with iostream activity to and from files.

I have built almost the entire project with no issues until today when I added a couple of methods that seem to have issues being found within the context of the definition file.

foo.h:

```
    #ifndef FOO_H
    #define FOO_H

    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>

    using std::string;
    using std::fstream;
    using std::vector;

    namespace FileSys
    {
        class foo
        {
        public:
            foo();
            /**
             * Attempts to open a file from directory dir
             * @param dir
             *              The path of the file to be opened
             */
            foo( string dir );
            /**
             * Attempts to find a directory using the parent file's path as the root directory and extending the directory by the child string
             * If child is null, the foo is replicated. Fails when parent.isDirectory() returns false.
             * @param parent
             *              The parent file to be used as the root path
             * @param child
             *              The child path to be used for extending the parent path
             */
            foo( foo &parent, string child );
            /**
             * Attempts to find a directory using the parent path as the root directory and extending the directory by the child string
             * If child is null, the foo is created with the parent path as the full path.
             * @param parent
             *              The parent path to be used as the root path
             * @param child
             *              The child path to be used for extending the parent path
             */
            foo( string parent, string child );
            /**
             * Attempts to clone reference to a previously existing foo file
             * @param file
             *              The file to be cloned
             */
            foo( foo &file );

            /**
             * Returns the working directory of this file
             */
            string getDir();

            /**
             * Writes the content supplied to the file, overwriting any existing data
             */
            bool writeTrunc( string content );

            /**
             * Writes the content supplied to the file, appending it to the end of the file
             */
            bool writeApp( string content );

            /**
             * Concatenates two files together. No implementation yet.
             */
            bool concatFiles( foo file1, foo file2 );

            /**
             * Reads from file
             *
             * @param length
             *              How many bytes will be retrieved from the file
             */
            string read( int length );

            /**
             * Reads from file
             *
             * @param length
             *              How many bytes will be retrieved from the file
             *
             * @param position
             *              Position to start reading from
             */
            string read( int length, int position );

            /**
             * Returns everything from the file
             */
            string readWholeFile();

            /**
             * Returns true if the file exists
             */
            bool exists();

            /**
             * Attempts to delete the current file
             * @return Returns true if successful and false otherwise
             *              The path of the file to be opened
             */
            bool deleteFile();

            /**
             * Returns true if this foo is a directory, rather than a file
             */
            bool isDirectory();

            /**
             * Returns the absolute path of the foo
             */
            string getAbsolutePath();

            /**
             * Returns the parent directory of this foo
             */
            foo getParentFile();

            /**
             * Creates all non-existent folders in mPath, creating the directory for this foo.
             */
            bool mkdirs();

            /**
             * Clean the file attributes
             */ 
            bool cleanFile();

            /**
             * Returns a list of all the directories and files contained within this directory 
             */
            vector<foo> list();

            /**
             * Deletes the file or directory from the file system
             */
            bool destroy();

            /**
             * Overrides the '=' operator to perform an assignment properly
             */
            foo& operator=(foo &file);

            /**
             * Overrides the '==' operator to perform an equality comparison on two foo
             */
            bool operator==(foo &file);

            /**
             * Overrides the '!=' operator to perform an inequality comparison on two foo
             */
            bool operator!=(foo &file);

            ~foo();
        protected:
        private:

            string mPath;
            fstream mFile;
            bool mExists;
            bool mIsFile;

            /**
             * Opens the file for operation
             * 
             * @param openMode
             *          The mode the file should be opened in. Use ios::openmode modes to determine the open mode.
             *
             * @return Returns true if successfully opened and false if failed
             */
            bool openFile( int openMode );

            /**
             * Indicates whether this foo is a file or a directory
             * Returns true if a file and false if a directory.
             */
            bool isFile();

            /**
             * Checks to see if the directory exists and attempts to create it if its parents exist
             *
             * @param dir
             *          The directory to be created
             *
             * @return Returns true if successful
             */
            bool mkdirs( foo dir );
    };

}

#endif // foo_H
```

foo.cpp:

```
    #include "foo.h"

    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <errno.h>
    #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
    #include <unistd.h>
    #endif /* HAVE_UNISTD_H */
    #include <sys/stat.h>

    using std::string;
    using std::fstream;
    using std::vector;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    #include <direct.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define mkdir(path,mode) _mkdir(path)
    #define getcwd _getcwd
    #endif

    #define ROOT_WORKING_DIRECTORY "SomeDir"

    namespace FileSys
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Ctors
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        foo::foo()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo::foo( string dir )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo::foo( foo &file )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo::foo( foo &parent, string child )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo::foo( string parent, string child )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Public methods
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        string foo::getDir()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::deleteFile()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::exists()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::writeApp( string content )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::writeTrunc( string content )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        string foo::read( int length )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        string foo::read( int length, int position )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        string foo::readWholeFile()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::isDirectory()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        string foo::getAbsolutePath()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo foo::getParentFile()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::mkdirs()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        foo& foo::operator=(foo &file)
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::operator==(foo &file)  //err 2039: 'operator==' is not a member of foo
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::operator!=(foo &file)  //err 2039: 'operator!=' is not a member of foo
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::cleanFile()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        vector<foo> foo::list()  //err 2039: 'list' is not a member of foo
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::destroy()  //err 2039: 'destroy' is not a member of foo
        { /*implementation*/ }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Private methods
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        bool foo::openFile( int openMode )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::isFile()
        { /*implementation*/ }

        bool foo::mkdirs( foo dir )
        { /*implementation*/ }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Dtors
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        foo::~foo()
        { /*implementation*/ }

    }
```

Any clues as to what I've done to create this issue?

Edit: I included the real code with only the class signature changed and the implementations removed. I have triple checked the syntax to ensure that I haven't misspelled the class name in the scope resolution of the methods that aren't working.

Comment: You've probably made a typo somewhere, but there's no way for us to tell because you haven't posted real code.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no preprocessor defines for `destroy` in any of  your header files?  Try `#undef destroy` before the definition.

Comment: @DeepYellow, if there was a macro renaming the function it would be reflected in the error message.

Comment: Hello, @nukeforum. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get more helpful responses if you post code that actually demonstrates the problem you are having. You have posted pseudo-code, and no error message. Please reduce your failing program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the problem and copy-paste that minimal program in your question. For more information, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @MarkRansom, you make a good point.  But when things are really weird it's worth eliminating the preprocessor as a culprit.  Consider for example, if an earlier include defines `destroy` so that it is defined for the header, but a later include defensively undefines it.  Unlikely?  Yes, but I've seen stranger!

Comment: @MarkRansom, in my experience, not always. This kind of problem crops up a lot in win32 where they use all kinds of macros in system headers... :/

Comment: Hi, @Rob, thanks for the advice. I tried to include as much of the actual code as possible. What is in the post is now a c/p of the code with the class signature changed and the implementations removed. I added a comment to the bottom saying this, but I triple-checked the spelling of the class name in the scope resolution, so I know the issue does not lie there.

Comment: @Nuke, you missed two key points of my advice. The most helpful sample program is a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem. Your program is complete (in that it compiles, at least), but it not minimal, nor does it demonstrate your problem. When I compile what you posted, there are no error messages. What happens when you compile *exactly* what you just posted?

Comment: I'm really confused now, as I can't seem to reproduce the problem except for in the project which I created it. Even if I nuke the files, create new ones, and paste the code into them; destroy(), list(), operator==(), and operator!=() are not recognized as existing in foo.

Comment: @Rob, sorry, what happens when I try to compile is that I get four errors of type C2039 saying that each of these methods (destroy(), list(), operator==(), and operator!=()) are not a member of FileSys::foo.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. Keep deleting lines of code. Eventually, you'll either have identified the line that breaks the system, or you'll have a 5-line, single-file program the demonstrates the error more clearly. Your sample above compiles perfectly well with g++ on Ubuntu 11.10. Maybe someone with visual c++ can give it a try.

Comment: @Rob I think the issue was with VS2010. I destroyed the whole project then re-added everything. This resolved the issue. Thanks for the help and being patient with me!

Answer (score 6):

We can't know (because you didn't post real C++), but my crystal ball says:

You have two copies of "foo.h". The one you edited is not the one that is being found by the `#include` directive.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but I saved out both files, opened them from the project's directory in a separate file editor and they both reflected the most recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I add appropriate return statements to the code you've posted, it compiles.

I still think the most likely cause is a typo somewhere - if you can't show us the exact code you're trying to compile, find someone who you can show the code to and ask them to double check it for you.